# exporting data to excel from c#.net environment(a simple .NET project to learn)

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, connection

Simply the project that i need to develop is all about taking daily accounts of couple branches of my shop.First and foremost,i need to get daily "pos amount(from debit cards or such etc)" and cash amount from branches manually(by calling them or on the intranet) then i calculate them to get daily income and total pos amount and total cahs amount.In addition to this, i wanted to develop a software to keep these data(with details) into a database which will be probably access(new table per day) and excel worksheet(new page for per day).Plus,between randomly chosen 2 days i want software to get pos or cahs or total income or maybe i need to be able to choose these dates and brances to calculate amount which i chose between specific dates...Now let's talk about the technical issues,firstly as a begginer developer i just developed an IDE to type amounts into and now trying to import these datas into excel workbook and worksheets but the problem is i cannot put the data regularly into rows...

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to store some data in Access do *NOT* do a new table per day.  Instead put the date in a field in the table.  You will be doing much, much more work if you have a table per day.

Excel isn't as good a choice as using Access tables as data types such as date/time, current, number or text reduces data errors.   Also Access databases allow for indexing on fields which can drastically decrease records searching and reporting times.